# rails how do I convert a variable into a symbol for use in a JSON string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

Trying to build a JSON string for use with a service and want to pass some of the JSON keys as variables.

I've tried:

```
def blah( field, value ) 
...
body = { request: { field.to_sym value } }
```

and

```
body = { request: { field.to_sym: value } }
```

but get errors in the console.  What's the proper syntax here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're looking for the hashrocket syntax:

```
body = { request: { field.to_sym => value } }
# -------------------------------^^
```

The JavaScript-style `k: v` notation can only be used with a limited set of literal symbols.

Comment: Getting used to using the newer syntax, I sometimes forget about good old hashrocket.  So simple. Many Thanks!